# why NONE shows after console asks to choose any options in PYTHON

Tags: python

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTWLJ.png)
 [OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFuKv.png)

In the output of  the program which I have attached in imaged 2 after console asks for option to choose before i enter anything to console None shows but my prog runs fine how to get rid of that None; plz refer the images i have attached.

```
from PIL import Image
image1=Image.open("chinu.jpg")
r,g,b=image1.split()

def red() :
    r.show()
def green() :
    g.show()
def blue() :
    b.show()

options = {1 : red,
           2 : green,
           3 : blue,
        }
while True:
    print(" 1-->  red   channel")
    print(" 2-->  green channel")
    print(" 3-->  blue  channel")
    num = int(input(print("enter your choice here = ")))
    options[num]()
    quits = str(input(print("IF YOU WANT TO CONTINUE PRESS Y  or press any key to quit")))
    if quits is "Y":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Post your code here, not a screenshot of it (unless you want us to post a screenshot of our answer)

Comment: sorry i am new to stack so iam posting code asap but i have added the screenshots here

Comment: How can we know that without any code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question...

Comment: Please don't YELL. If you need to emphasize something you can [use Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input(x)` will print `x` for you. You don't need to `input(print(y))`. In fact what that means is that it will also print `x = print(y) = None` which is what you're seeing.